# C++ How to fill a vector of undefined size with strings?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to get a user-inputted string to be split up and stored in a vector character by character. However, when the string is inputted and entered, I get this error:

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Program: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140D.dll
>
> File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\vector
>
> Line: 1234
>
> Expression: vector subscript out of range

I've tried researching vectors to see if I'm implementing it correctly but from what I can see it appears I am.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void rovarspraket(); //declaration because I like to put my functions after main()

int main() {
    rovarspraket(); //function call

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void rovarspraket() { //the function
    string sText; //string that will be inputted
    vector<string> vText; //vector that sText will go into

    cout << "Input text to be encoded to Rovarspraket: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, sText); //gimme dat sText

    cout << "\n\n"; //pretty formatting, just ignore

    for (int i = 0; i < sText.length(); ++i) {
        vText[i] = sText[i]; //slap that character into the vector
        cout << vText[i] << endl; //just to test what was actually happening
    }
}
```

Comment: Vectors don't grow on trees. If you want to explicitly add something to a vector, use `resize()` or `push_back()`. `operator[]` replaces an existing value in the vector. Your vector is empty, so `operator[]` results in undefined behavior.

Comment: [std::vector::push_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/)

Comment: `vText[i] = sText[i];` why does this even compile. Again this awful null to string conversion?

Comment: @BlackMoses , why wouldn't it compile? The return type of `std::vector<std::string>::operator[]` is `std::string&`. `std::string` exposes an `operator=` taking a `char`. Perfectly legal syntax from a compiler's point of view.

Comment: @Alejandro Well, I didn't even know about this `operator=` overload. Why would anyone use it anyway... If one want to store `char`, than it should be stored in `char`, not `std::string`

Comment: @Alejandro I like to use strings instead of chars because strings are more easily combined with other strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sam Varshavchik said it already, I'd like to explain it a little bit more though. But basically your trying to assign the first element of a vector to something else, but the issue is that your vector is empty, so there's no element to assign! Use .push_back() to add an element to the end of the vector. So your "for" loop should look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sText.length(); ++i) {
    vText.push_back(sText[i]);
    cout << vText[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and since the vector is a string vector, I get an error when I try to put the char(?) of `sText[i]` into the `vText[i]` index of vText

Comment: @Hunter, You can construct a `std::string` from a single `char` if you use [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). Since `push_back` is overloaded to take a temporary `std::string`, you can simply modify Mark's loop to say `push_back({sText[i]});` (notice the extra curly braces).

Comment: Thank you Mark, this works. However, when the program is run, the first character of the inputted string is ignored, and all the subsequent characters are placed in the vector. For example, if the inputted string was "hello", the vector, starting from element 0, looks like `[e] [l] [l] [o]`

Answer (score 2):

Your question asks "vector of undefined size", but

```
std::vector<std::string> vText;
```

does not have an undefined size: it has a size of *zero*.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    std::cout << v.size() << "\n";
}
```

has well defined behavior - it prints 0: http://ideone.com/JW2LDH

What is happening in your code is that you are performing accesses beyond the end of the current data:

```
std::vector<std::string> v;
v[0] = "";  // Undefined Behavior: v has size 0
```

There are several ways to add data to a vector:

```
std::vector::push_back
    v.push_back("hello");
```

This grows the data size by one and default constructs the new element, then copies the argument into it.

```
std::vector::emplace_back (since c++11)
    v.emplace_back("hello");
```

similar to push_back but instead of default-ctor+copy it simply in-place creates the new element.

```
std::vector::resize(N);  // allocates and default-ctors elements
    v.resize(5);
    v[0] = "hello";
    v[4] = "world";
    v[5] = "";  // UB, beyond end of data
```

grows or shrinks the array size to N. In all cases of growth, it may cause a new allocation and a resulting copy of all existing elements into the new space.

To avoid this, you can use `std::vector::reserve(N)` to allocate space for upto N elements ahead of time - this can help the performance of push_back/emplace_back.

```
std::vector::insert(iterator, value);
    v.insert(v.begin(), "hello");  // at front
    v.insert(v.begin() + 1, "world");  // after 'hello'
    std::cout << v[0] << v[1];  // "helloworld"
    std::cout << v[2];  // UB, beyond end of data
```

Inserts elements at a given iterator position.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize a vector, you're giving it a default space (I think a space of 8 objects were reserved).

If you pass a string short enough nothing bad might not happen, but if the string length is larger than the objects reserved in the vector, you're basically trying to assign something that exists (the char of the string) to something that doesn't exist (the space in that vector).

Some thing you can do is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vText.size(); ++i) {
    vText[i] = sText[i];
    cout << vText[i] << endl;
} // So you never exceed vector's allocated space.
  // Beware tho, that string might not be fully copied into the vector.
```

or (this one is the ideal)

```
for (int i = 0; i < sText.length(); ++i) {
    vText.push_back(sText[i]);
    cout << vText[i] << endl;
}
```

You can also initialize the vector with a huge gap of space, but it is a waste of resources:

```
vector<string> vText(200) // You'd have space for 200 strings of chars ("h" for example)
```

Comment: The default size is zero. You're talking about default capacity

Answer (score 0):

Vectors in STL are object representing a kind of "dynamic array". Thus, simply initialized, they do not reserve any memory for its data. If you know the size in advance (but for a reason, you do not want to use an array), you can first initialize the vector with:

```
std::vector<std::string> vect;
```

Then call `reserve()` on it to reserve a certain amount of element :

```
vect.reserve(4);    // Reserve 4 "memory space" for elements
```

Don't forget that the only portable way to access the elements of the vector is to use an iterator (easy to do with the `auto` keyword in C++11), such as:

```
for (auto iter = vect.begin(); iter != vect.end(); iter++) {
    *iter = valueToAssignToArray;
}
```

Otherwise, as suggested by others, you can simply use the `push_back` method to call the copy-constructor of the object you want to add to the vector (in this case, the copy-constructor of `string`, which means the string gets copied to the vector) or the `emplace_back` method which calls to constructor of the object directly (no need to initialize the object before adding it to the vector).